# php file is working on local server but fails when on online server

Tags: php, mysql

I did complete a website for online Entrance form for students as my demo project to learn. When I run from my local server it works fine but when I uploaded on webserver and tasted index.php and other files run fine except when user enter his/her symbol no to check if he/she already been registered or not..I have coded  a logic

if (exists)>Show admit card 
if(don't exist)>show alert box

It works fine in local server but in webserver when I enter value in search box and enter then it shows empty page with no any error.

I have one row in my database. So in case you wanna check here is the symbol no in column =15369-2017-02 . On Entering submit it should show admit card and you can enter any random value other then this .which should show alert box.

Here is my website

https://cmprc.edu.np/condensed/entrance_form_demo/studntreport/main/

This is the code of file which is not responding and showing blank

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>
CDP || Admission Form
    </title>

     <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="../style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />


    <body style="background-color: white;">






   <?php
      include('../connect.php');
    $var_value = $_POST['search_value'];
    echo $var_value;

    $sql="SELECT * FROM entrance WHERE re_value='$var_value'";
    $STH = $db->prepare($sql);
    $STH->execute(array($var_value));
    $User = $STH->fetch();

    if (empty($User))

      echo "<script>alert('Sorry, you Have not Registered yet');
            window.location = 'index.php';</script>"; 
    else
            $result = $db->prepare("SELECT *  FROM entrance
                                    WHERE re_value = '$var_value' ORDER BY id ASC;");
            $result->execute();
            for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); ){

          ?>


    <link href="../style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <center><h4><i class="icon-edit icon-large"></i> You've Already Registered</h4></center>
    <hr>




    <center>

      <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 seventy">
           <img src="img/admit.png"/ >

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8 thirty">

      <img src="../image/profile/<?php echo $row['pic_value'];?>" class="roundimage2"   alt=""/>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <hr>
    <table style=" width: 500px;">

      <tr>
    <td >Roll no: </td>
    <td> <?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
      </tr>

    <tr>
    <td >Name : </td>
    <td > <?php echo $row['name_en_value']; ?></td>


    <td > Subject:  </td>
    <td > <?php echo $row['ge_value']; ?> </td>
     </tr>
    </table>

    <br><br>
    <h5><i><strong>STUDENTS MUST BRING THIS ADMIT CARD ON THE DAY OF EXAMINATION</strong></i></h5>

    <br>
  </div>
  </center>


    <?php
    }
    ?>

    </body>
    <?php include('footer.php');?>

    </html>
```

Any help? I did almost finished it which I was working continously for 4-5 Days.

Comment: **WARNING**: Whenever possible use **prepared statements** to avoid injecting arbitrary data in your queries and creating [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Comment: is that a reason why this page is not  showing anything?

Comment: It's something you should fix to narrow down the possible problems. A "no content" result is often the consequence of an error in your code, so check your error logs first to find out what's going wrong.

Comment: The webpage is not showing anything because the interpretation stops before outputting anything. Look at the my.php result page in Source Code view (STRG+U) and you can see that there is indeed some code.

Comment: @TimS okay then  what should i must i do then??

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your php is not executed correctly. Maybe try to enable error reporting to get a hint of what's wrong.

Include the following at the beginning of your destination file (my.php)

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Comment: okay I've added line at begigning and uploaded on server and what next?

Comment: That's interesting. Now there is no output at all so it seems that even this code fails. Maybe you are not allowed to enable error reporting which doesn't help. Try to remove one line or the other to see if you get any output.

Comment: The problem definately lies inside your connect.php. If you open this file

https://cmprc.edu.np/condensed/entrance_form_demo/studntreport/connect.php

you receive a 500 (internal server error). Because of this error your script is not further executed.
You should resolve the errors in this file first to get the my.php working

Comment: I double checked ...there is no any problem in connect.php and else I'm able to inset a new row form apply online and filling out the form also...I have updated again pleae check.

Comment: fixed that .found it  problem was with my connect.php..thanks for guidance.